# Highcharts area charts with single data, not rendering

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have an area chart with three series x-axis is 'datetype', when there is only data in each series the labels on x and y axis appears as expected but the plot point is missing. Can't expect a filled area for one data but even the plot point is missing. 
'minRange' property is set and so the label is showing the date from the data.
Is this expected or there is a property that needs to be set to see the plot points.

fiddle link here http://jsfiddle.net/bM9j9/6/

```
$(function () {
 $('#container').highcharts({
 chart: {
  type: 'area'
},
title: {
  text: 'Area chart'
},
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  minRange: 864e5
},
yAxis: {
  min: 0
    //tickInterval: 0.5,
    //minRange: 0.5
},
credits: {
  enabled: false
},
plotOptions: {
  area: {
    stacking: 'normal',
    marker: {
      enabled: false,
      symbol: 'circle',
      radius: 2,
      states: {
        hover: {
          enabled: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
series: [{
  name: 'Open',
  data: [
    [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 3), 120]
  ]
}, {
  name: 'Closed',
  data: [
    [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 3), 60]
  ]
}, {
  name: 'Accepted',
  data: [
    [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 3), 89]
  ]
}]
 });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually the data is rendered, But you cannot see it because the marker radius of the point is 0 in normal sate but it will be visible when your mouse hovers on it.

this is happening because you have disabled marker and have enabled hover for it.

To get the points visible turn them on.

```
plotOption: {
    area:{
        marker: {
            enabled: true,
-----continue with other properties----
        }
    }
}
```

updated your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bM9j9/7/

Hope this will help you.